# What is the equivalent of adding an integer to a color in new SASS?

Tags: css, sass, colors, dart-sass

For a while, [color arithmetic in SASS has been deprecated](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2144) and not available in newer versions of the tool. I am currently migrating an older project which had color arithmetic.

For example, the older scss files has something like this:

```
background: $body-bg-color-dark-light + 10;
```

`$body-bg-color-dark-light` is a simple RGB value (like #FF1100)

What is the alternative using [the new SASS color functions](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color) to reproduce the exact same functionality as above? Note that we are adding a simple integer and not a percentage.

Alternative I have tried is:

```
background: lighten($body-bg-color-dark-light, 10); 
// Note that '10' is not a percentage in the previous example
```

This does not produce the desired color. Also, since `lighten` and `darken` accept only percentages I am confused about the values that are greater than `100` in the code base that I am migrating.

The other problem is I am not able to obtain an older version of SASS (or locate which version for that matter) to figure what exactly was produced by simply adding an integer to a color so that I could apply the new color functions to produce the same result.

Edit:

I managed to dig up an old compiled version of that SCSS. One original value in that sample was `#020507`.

Adding `10` to that produced a result of `#0c0f11`. Looks like it is adding `10` (or `A` in hex) to every color channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** thanks to the new example provided by OP the first hypothesis can be confirmed:

```
#020507 + 10 = #020507 + #0A0A0A = #0C0F11
```

---

*I will make some conjectures here, but I can't seem to find an example similar to yours.*

---

On the [SASS documentation about operators](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators) you can read:

> Early on in Sass’s history, it added support for mathematical operations on [colors](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/colors). These operations operated on each of the colors’ RGB channels separately, so adding two colors would produce a color with the sum of their red channels as its red channel and so on.

Here are some examples given [here](https://vanseodesign.com/css/sass-colors-part-1/) and [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/sass/sass-operators):

```
#020406 + #020406 = #04080c
#020406 * 2 = #04080c
#102030 + #010203 = #112233
#101010 * 2 = #202020
```

In your example, an integer is added to the color; assuming that it's a decimal value, its hexadecimal value would be `A`.

---

#### - 1st hypothesis (correct)

If we do the operation as explained in the doc, it would mean that:

```
#FF1100 + 10 = #FF1100 + #0A0A0A
```

According to [this calculator](https://www.calculator.net/hex-calculator.html?number1=FF1100&c2op=%2B&number2=0A0A0A&calctype=op&x=69&y=12), the result would be:

```
#FF1100 + #0A0A0A = 1091B0A
```

I don't know very well how hexadecimal values work, but since the result is not a valid color I will assume that the red channel ignores the addition (since it already has the max value). So in the end we have:

```
#FF1100 + 10 = #FF1B0A
```

Now, the equivalent using SASS color functions would be using [`adjust-color`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/color#adjust):

```
adjust-color(#FF1100, $red: 10, $green: 10, $blue: 10);
```

---

#### - 2nd hypothesis (incorrect)

The value is only added as it and not to each channels separately. So, using the [same calculator](https://www.calculator.net/hex-calculator.html?number1=FF1100&c2op=%2B&number2=A&calctype=op&x=59&y=20):

```
#FF1100 + 10 = #FF1100 + A = #FF110A
```

And the equivalent with `ajust-color`:

```
adjust-color(#FF1100, $blue: 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to draft up this reply! Your answer helped me dig deeper into this. I have updated my question. Looks like your first hypothesis was correct. If you can edit your answer to reflect that I will accept this.

Comment: @NandeepMali Ahh! I'm glad you found a compiled version of your code to determine which of these two hypothesis was correct. I was really curious about this too. What kind of edit do you want me to do? Remove the second hypothesis?

Comment: I think a simple statement highlighting which hypothesis was correct. The 2nd one contains a useful example so it might be handy for someone else.